# How to two-way bind v-model object in vue class style component with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I would like to create a custom component in vue cli where I can use the v-model for passing a value (or object) to my component. As I understand, when I use v-model for binding I can update the passed value in the parent. Either you can tick the checkbox or click the button to set the value to true.

In app code:

```
 <test v-model="content"></test>
    <br />
    selected: {{content}}
```

Test component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field label="Regular" v-model="checkval" disabled></v-text-field>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      v-bind:checked="checkval"
      v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    />
    <v-btn @click="$emit('change', true)">Make true</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Model, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component({
  model: {
    prop: "checkval",
    event: "change"
  },
  props: {
    checkval: Boolean
  }
})
export default class test extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Now I would like to go the next step and implement my component as "[class style](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components)" and two-way bind an object. I tried the following, but that didn't work (the previous code with Boolean worked fine):

```
export class myobject {
    checkval!: boolean;
    test!: String;
}

@Component
export default class test extends Vue {
    @Prop() checkval: Boolean = false;
    @Model() model: myobject = {
        checkval: true,
        test: "checkval"
    };
}
```

Now my questions:

1. How would I do this when binding an object?
2. Is there a way I don't have to use the `Emit` and just set the variable like `checkval = true` or `model.checkval = true` ?
3. When I have to use the `Emit`, how would the correct code look for the button, like
   `<v-btn @click="$emit('change', {...this.model, checkval: true})">` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and finally found the answer on the [vue-property-decorator github](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator):

**@Model(event?: string, options: (PropOptions | Constructor[] | Constructor) = {}) decorator**

```
import { Vue, Component, Model } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
  @Model('change', { type: Boolean }) readonly checked!: boolean
}
```

is equivalent to

```
export default {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    checked: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  }
}
```

@Model property can also set type property from its type definition via reflect-metadata .

Answer (score 0):

Try use [`VModel`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#-vmodelpropsargs-propoptions-decorator).

```
import { Vue, Component, VModel } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class YourComponent extends Vue {
  @VModel({ type: String }) name!: string
}
```